# Dans quel(s) cas choisir le nom masculin « allié » ou féminin « alliée » ?

Tags: genre, noms

Bonjour.

Je suis prise d'un énorme doute sur le choix du mot « allié » en tant que nom au masculin ou au féminin dans l'accroche qui suit:

> Faites de l'information votre **allié** stratégique

Le mot « allié » est ici utilisé comme un nom commun (et non un participe passé du verbe « allier ») mais j'hésite à l'orthographier au masculin ou au féminin. Le nom « information » est un nom féminin. Mais ce n'est pas une « chose » ni un « objet », mais plutôt un concept qui se cache derrière. J'ai l'impression que les 2 solutions ne sont pas des fautes mais j'aimerais néanmoins des avis externes !

Je vous remercie d'avance :-)

Edit: Pour ma part, je trouve que les deux formes passent. Si quelqu'un détient donc une information qui fait qu'une des deux formes est une faute, je suis preneuse. Sinon, je considérerais les deux formes comme correctes et défendables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un **adjectif substantivé**, qui n'a pas de genre et nombre a priori.

On peut donc employer au choix, **hors d'autres contraintes**, un allié, une alliée, des alliés.

Dans le cas cité, il est **obligatoire de l'accorder avec le sujet**, puisqu'il le **précise**:

> **L'information est alliée avec toi => Elle est ton alliée stratégique.**
>
> Elle est ton amie. (on ne dirait pas : elle est ton ami).

Avec un nom commun, il n'y a pas d'accord obligatoire, même sur le nombre:

> Ces difficultés sont ton problème.

Voir sur [CNRTL des exemples précis d'accord](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alli%C3%A9):

> si la vérité se répand, ils sont perdus! La république, au contraire,
> n'a pas de meilleure alliée.

Comment: Merci c'est extrêmement clair et cela ne laisse plus place au doute. Pil ce que j'attendais ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Pour aider, on peut dire :

> Faites de l'information **une** alliée stratégique.

Ici il est clair que "alliée" est un nom commun, et donc s'accorde.
On a donc de même :

> Faites de l'information votre allié**e** stratégique.

**Edit**:
Comme [guillaume](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/8994/guillaume-girod-vitouchkina) le fait remarqué, « Allié(e) » est un nom à double genre, ce qui n'est pas le cas de tous les noms communs: on peut autant dire « Un allié » que « Une alliée ». On trouve en effet dans la définition le type "nom", et non "nom masculin" ou "nom féminin" (Cf [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/alli%C3%A9_alli%C3%A9e/2377) et [L'internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/allie/))

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ta réponse. Penses-tu également que l'utilisation du nom "allié" au masculin pourrait être perçu comme une faute ou est-ce quand-même défendable ? Si je reprends ta phrase "Faites de l'information un allié stratégique", est-ce que cela te dérange/t'interpelle ?

Comment: Cette phrase ressemble à un slogan publicitaire non ? Si c'est destiné à être publié (publicité, magazine, prospectus...) ou si c'est destiné à la hiérarchie (votre patron(ne)), aucune faute n'est tolérée. Si c'est un message que vous envoyez à quelqu'un que vous connaissez, c'est une erreur commune et qui ne s'entend pas à l'oral, donc on vous pardonnerai :)

Comment: J'allais répondre mais tu as tout dit alors... :p

Comment: Oui, il s'agit d'une accroche imprimée sur des flyers. C'est pourquoi cela m'amène à en débattre ici! Il me faudrait pour bien faire un argumentaire comme quoi une des deux formes constitue une erreur.

Comment: La réponse est correcte, l'explication n'a pas de sens: un nom commun a un genre qui lui est propre. On ne peut pas le changer : "Ton discours est une bêtise."  par exemple.  -1

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina en effet c'est intéressant... Il y a des noms communs qui ont un genre fixe, et d'autres non... je vais faire une recherche sur ce point :)